# Message: Trying to get property 'firstname' of non-object Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**view**

```
<form action="/user/edit" method="POST">


           <?php $fuser = $this->session->userdata('fname');?> <input name="firstname" class="input" type="text" value="<?php echo $fuser->firstname;?>" placeholder="Enter First Name"><br><br>

            <?php $luser = $this->session->userdata('lname');?> <input name="lastname" class="input" type="text" value="<?php echo $luser->lastname;?>" placeholder="Enter Last Name"><br><br>

             <?php $grd = $this->session->userdata('grade');?> <input name="grade" class="input" type="text" value="<?php echo $grd->grade;?>" placeholder="Enter Grade"><br><br>

             <?php $euser = $this->session->userdata('email');?><input name="email" class="input" type="text" value="<?php echo $euser->email;?>" placeholder="Enter Email"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" class="btn btn-default "/>

</form>
```

**controller**

```
public function edit()
    {
    $this->load->library('session');


    $this->load->view('edit');
    }
```

after running i get the following errors:
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'firstname' of non-object

Filename: views/edit.php

Line Number: 33

Comment: In your <form> you've written ```value="<?php echo $fuser->firstname;?>"```
should not it be ```value="<?php echo $fuser;?>"``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is really not so clear but the non-object error comes when you try to access an object with the [] like `obj_var["index"]` or an array with -> like `$arr_var->index`. I suggest you use `var_dump($variable)` on the variable you tried to access and see how to access the variable properly.

You can also cast the variable to an object or array depending on how you wish to use it.
To convert to array use the below.

```
$array_cast = (array) $your_variable;
```

or
To convert to object use the below.

```
$object_cast = (object) $your_variable;
```